# Random numbers added to extjs data store ajax call

Tags: extjs4, datastore

```
 var resource_store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
 pageSize: 10,
autoLoad: true,
fields: ['id','r_number','c_number','resource_name','resource_desc','resource_url','resource_file'],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: BASE_URL+'courses/resources/displayResources/'+course_id,
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'results'
   }
},
storeId: 'id'
});
```

I'm using Extjs4 data store like this way.
When i see the ajax calls a random number is appended to the url

```
http://localhost/Edu_web/index.php/courses/resources/displayResources/PTGRE14?_dc=1328442262503&page=1&start=0&limit=10
```

Even though i use 
`actionMethod:{
read: 'POST'
}`.

?_dc=1328442262503 still appears in the url.

how to remove these parameters in url. and send any parameters through POST

Comment: This parameters don't make any troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even though i use actionMethod:{ read: 'POST' }.
>
> ?_dc=1328442262503 still appears in the url.

Of course it would. You should use `actionMethods` (with 's' at the end).

To remove _dc from GET request you should add `noCache: false` to proxy's config. [Docs for noCache](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-noCache).

P.S. Using a POST for reading is a bad practise. You should only use a POST when you are modifying data on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any proxy in your network, before disabling the random number, check to see if they have caching disabled, otherwise the client, instead of downloading the updated pages from the server, will continue to read the previous ones stored in the proxy. The random number added to the call makes it different each time and the proxy will be forced to always download it from the server